# Error para redireccionar la pagina con PHP

Tags: php, servidor, redirección

Monte mi aplicación web a un servidor web, en local todo funciona perfectamente, las peticiones entre otras cosas, tengo un sistema de paginas para usuarios registrados y logeados, las manipulo con sesiones, verificaciones entre otras cosas, cada pagina (usuarios registrados) tiene una verificación en las cabeceras que se encarga de comprobar y validar los usuarios por motivos de seguridad a través de un código backend que tengo, si las condiciones no se cumplen es decir que no pasa por el sistema de verificación que tengo no se crean la sesiones y si no se crean la sesiones los mando al index.php, aquí el código para entender mejor lo que digo.

```html
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || (!isset($_SESSION['nick'])) ){
        header("Location: index.php?session=TimeOut");
        exit();
    }else{      
        if($_SESSION['user']!=$_SESSION['name_validate'] || $_SESSION['id']!=$_SESSION['id_user']||$_SESSION['user_validate']!=$_SESSION['permise'] || $_SESSION['data_validate']!=$_SESSION['random'] ){
            header("Location: index.php?access=Denied");
            exit();
        }                    
    }    
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

También lo intente de esta forma:

```html
<?php
/* Redirecciona a una página diferente en el mismo directorio el cual se hizo la petición */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>

//Del manual de PHP
```

Como verán están ante cualquier entrada del html o de datos, por lo que deberia funcionar, además la consola no me marca ningun tipo de error, por lo que no se donde esta el problema.En resumen este código fue hecho para evitar que los usuarios coloquen la URL directamente sin logearse

Comment: No puede haber absolutamente nada antes de la etiqueta `<?php`, ni siquiera un espacio... Además, la redirección tiene que ser a una ruta absoluta, no se permiten rutas relativas

Comment: Puedes ver las cabeceras de las peticiones http en el inspector de tu navegador? deberías poder ver las rutas y los redireccionamientos ahi :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolverlo añade `ob_start();` justo después de `session_start();` tomando tu código quedaría así:

```
 <?php 
        session_start();
        ob_start();

        if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || (!isset($_SESSION['nick'])) ){
            header("Location: index.php?session=TimeOut");
            exit();
        }else{      

            if($_SESSION['user']!=$_SESSION['name_validate'] || $_SESSION['id']!=$_SESSION['id_user']||$_SESSION['user_validate']!=$_SESSION['permise'] || $_SESSION['data_validate']!=$_SESSION['random'] ){
               header("Location: index.php?access=Denied");
               exit();
            }                    
        }    
?>
```

Aquí te dejo la guía e información acerca de esta función en PHP:

[**ob_start();**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ob-start.php)

¡Espero que te sirva de ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

¿Podrá ser que la variable de sesión ya exista pero esté vacía (o sea que `$_SESSION['user'] = '';`)? En ese caso tu expresión `if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))` devolverá `true` y no te enviará al index.

Para asegurarte, después del `session_start();` inicial agrega un `print_r($_SESSION);`. Ahí verás si las variables ya fueron inicializadas antes de la validación. Si lo están, basta que hagas un `unset($_SESSION);` (una única vez) antes de volver a probar.